# R rvest: could not find function "xpath_element"

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, rvest, httr, xml2

I am trying to simply replicate the example of `rvest::html_nodes()`, yet encounter an error:

```
library(rvest)
ateam <- read_html("http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ateam.htm")
html_nodes(ateam, "center")
```

> Error in do.call(method, list(parsed_selector)) :    could not find
>   function "xpath_element"

The same happens if I load packages such as `httr`, `xml2`, `selectr`. I seem to have the latest version of these packages too...

In which packages are functions such as `xpath_element`, `xpath_combinedselector` located? How do I get it to work? Note that I am running on Ubuntu 16.04, so that code might work on other platforms...

Comment: Perhaps R just knows you're violating a site's terms of service and refuses to help you just (which would be a good course of action for anyone thinking of helping enable content theft).

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you update R, and packages?

Comment: Thanks for checking @cory ! On which platform/R version are you?

Comment: I had a similar problem that I'm having difficulty in reproducing (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, R 3.3.2). See if 'selectr' is working properly with something like `selectr::css_to_xpath("#selectr")`

Comment: `install.packages("selectr")` worked for me after that.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this issue is rather old but I wanted to post a comment for those who may have similar issues.

I stumbled upon [this same error](https://github.com/timtrice/rrricanes/issues/67) and was unable to find much help. So, I thought instead of targeting CSS I would try to target the xpath instead. I do not know what the best practice is.

My original functions worked fine on Ubuntu 16, R 3.4.0. However, they failed on Debian 8 R 3.3.3 and R 3.4.0.

When I modified my code to target xpaths instead of css they began working as expected. For example, changing this...

```
contents <- link %>% 
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(css = "pre") %>%
    rvest::html_text()
```

to this...

```
contents <- link %>%
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(xpath = "//pre") %>%
    rvest::html_text()
```

resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @tbrugz, the issue seems to come form package `selectr`.

This happens however only when the package is installed with apt-get install r-cran-selectr. Installing the package with sudo R, then install.packages works fine.

```
pkg <- installed.packages()
subset(as.data.frame(pkg), Package=="selectr", c("Package", "LibPath"))
      Package                                         LibPath
  selectr   selectr /home/matifou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3
  selectr.1 selectr                         /usr/lib/R/site-library
library(selectr, lib.loc="/home/matifou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3")
css_to_xpath(".testclass")
  [1] "descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-    space(@class), ' '), ' testclass ')]"

detach("package:selectr", unload=TRUE)

library(selectr, lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
css_to_xpath(".testclass")
  Error in do.call(method, list(parsed_selector)) :
```

could not find function "xpath_class"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating `xml2` directly to my local R library rather than relying on `rvests` imports.

`install.packages("xml2")`

Answer (score 0):

had same problem. I had installed `rverse` directly from Jupyter notebook on the macOS 10.13.5. Reinstalling `rverse` directly from the `r-shell` fixed this for me. 
Steps:
1. type `r` in terminal and press `enter`.
2. `install.packages('rvest')`