# Error when using html_nodes from rvest package

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest

I am trying to run Hadley Wickham's code from his GitHub [here](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/demo/tripadvisor.R). When I run the below code:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g37209-d1762915-`Reviews-JW_Marriott_Indianapolis-Indianapolis_Indiana.html"`

reviews <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")
```

I get the following error:

Error in xpath_combinedselector(): could not find function "xpath_combinedselector"
Traceback:

1. url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[k])
8. function_list[k]
9. html_nodes(., "#REVIEWS .innerBubble")
10. html_nodes.default(., "#REVIEWS .innerBubble")
11. xml2::xml_find_all(x, make_selector(css, xpath))
12. xml_find_all.xml_node(x, make_selector(css, xpath))
13. xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = Inf)
14. make_selector(css, xpath)
15. selectr::css_to_xpath(css, prefix = ".//")
16. tran$css_to_xpath(sel, pref)
17. sapply(selectors, function(selector) selector_to_xpath(selector, 
    .     prefix))
18. lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
19. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
20. selector_to_xpath(selector, prefix)
21. .self$xpath(tree)
22. do.call(method, list(parsed_selector))

I have tried rewriting the code without pipes, installing the selectr package and expressly installing the xml2 package, but nothing has worked. I am a beginner so forgive me if I have missed something obvious.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874011/r-rvest-could-not-find-function-xpath-element

Comment: Hello @EttoreRizza - I did look at that question but the top answer didn't work for me, and I've already tried the third answer. The second answer appears to point to a bug in the rvest package, so perhaps that's what the issue is?

Comment: Maybe an issue with the `selectr` package. Could you try to reinstall it ?

Comment: I tried unstalling, reinstalling and rerunning everything, and it appears to have worked. Since the fix was similar to the question suggested in the comment by @EttoreRizza, I will flag this question as a dupe.